# Calling multicall contract using Go

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I'm trying to make a multicall using go. The function "aggregate" takes a tuple of "calls" with address and bytes.

```
        "name": "aggregate",
        "inputs": [
            {
                "type": "tuple[]",
                "name": "calls",
                "components": [
                    {
                        "type": "address",
                        "name": "target"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "bytes",
                        "name": "callData"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

In Go, I first defined a type struct of "Call" with common.Address and []byte

```
type Call struct {
    target   common.Address
    callData []byte
}
```

When I put an array of "Call" in "multiCallAggregate.Inputs.Pack([]Call{data})", it always packs an empty []byte. Am I doing something wrong in the Call struct? Thank you!

```
ERC20BalanceOf := ERC20rAbi.Methods["balanceOf"]
    comptrolleId := ERC20BalanceOf.ID
    inputs, err := ERC20BalanceOf.Inputs.Pack(
        common.HexToAddress("0xd6801a1DfFCd0a410336Ef88DeF4320D6DF1883e"),
    )
    inputs = append(comptrolleId[:], inputs[:]...)

    ERC20Address := common.HexToAddress("0xab5801a7d398351b8be11c439e05c5b3259aec9b")

    data := Call{target: ERC20Address, callData: inputs}

    multiCallAggregate := multicallAbi.Methods["aggregate"]
    multicallInputs, err := multiCallAggregate.Inputs.Pack([]Call{data})
    fmt.Println(multicallInputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

multicall input for golang is `data [][]byte`. no need to use any structs and all call's target is the same contract so you need to create `[]byte` for every call and pack them together as input for multicall